# How to organize and label methods intended for debug?

Tags: c++, interfaces

I have a class `System`, which uses a bunch of other classes, to achieve some complex signal processing.

In debugging `System`, one needs to observe the output signal for patterns. This is not achievable by a debugger, because of the large number of samples going through.

However, if certain parts of `System` can be isolated and hooked to the environment, instead of `System`, this will allow for simpler transformations to be performed on the signal. Thus, it becomes easier to see if those individual parts are working.

This is in addition to tests to each class, that comprises `System`. Once integrated, the otherwise working components may exhibit bugs. Furthermore, testing 2 or 3 of those chained together is another approach to understanding why `System` is not performing correctly.

Consequently, methods were introduced in `System` to hook various inters from/to the environment. Those methods are not needed to a final user of the class, but also cannot be removed.

How can these methods be arranged, named, and mixed-in so that the interface is clear to an end user of the class? Also, while still providing the debugging behavior hacks?

Comment: Why can't you use a debugger for debugging, which would save the need for any specialized accessors?

Comment: @Sven, see the part after the asterisk. Sub-sytems need to be connected to the environment. Running a debugger through System is not feasable, because the System is complicated. I need to replace it with only parts of it. This happens by connecting the environmental inputs/outputs to internal points in `System`.

Comment: I don't understand what you do there. I can't imagine a system where you can't use a debugger. If you want to debug only part of the system, run the debugger in a test environment. Anyways, logging is the logical alternative, as mentioned below.

Comment: @Sven, I will try to reword the question to make it clear.

Comment: @Sven:Debuggers are only mildly helpful in debugging embedded, real-time and multi-threaded systems. They tend to totally mess up timing, especially if timers and interrupts are triggering in the background. While debuggers are very helpful during initial development, once you start trying to track down problems at a system level, logging is the far more effective approach. The logging tells you where the problem is likely occurring, then you may be able to figure out where to set that breakpoint to pinpoint the exact error conditions.

Comment: Although, I agree with Sven in regards to not really wanting to have specialized accessors in classes just for debug. We always have a LogPriority that is used by the logging module that can be set dynamically. If the priority of the log entry isn't high enough then it isn't logged. That way we can turn off/filter debug info as desired.

Comment: @Dunk I see no hints to embedded, real-time, or multi-threaded nature of the system in question. Anyways, my goal was just to know why debugging isn't feasible. I still don't really know why, but I also think it's futile to discuss this further, as logging seems to be the way he should go.

Comment: @Sven, the application is embedded and (soft)realtime, but that's not the issue. `System` is a class that configures some hardware, that does some processing. The correctness of `System` is based on the output of that hardware. There must be a way for some of that hardware to be circumvented. That's it.

Comment: @Sven:I read the description and thought nothing but embedded, multithreaded and real-time so there had to be some hints. Anyways, I was more directly giving you examples of where a debugger is not appropriate because you stated "I can't imagine a system where you can't use a debugger".

Comment: @Dunk: You found the hints, because Vorac rewrote most of the questions after my initial comments, as you can see from his comment before your first.

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction is that you should examine the possibility to use e.g. event tracing or logging in order to observe the system's behavior instead of having explicit methods in your class. Existing frameworks often gives you the possibility to modify levels of output dynamically, i.e. at run time, with overhead that is acceptable for most environments.

That being said, if this is really the way you want to go, maybe something like this would be a bit cleaner (pseudo code, not C++):

```
interface IDebugInfo
{
  int SomeDebugCounter();
}

interface IDebugInfoProvider
{
  IDebugInfo GetDebugInfo();
}

class System
  : IDebugInfoProvider
{
  class SystemDebugInfo : IDebugInfo
  {}

  IDebugInfo GetDebugInfo()
  {
    return new SystemDebugInfo(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might read about [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/), which is relevant only if `NDEBUG` is not preprocessor defined.

So this suggests to wrap your debug-specific code with

```
 #ifndef NDEBUG
    //// debug specific code
 #endif
```

and you could compile your production binary with `-DNDEBUG` ...

My preference is simply to mention e.g. `dbg` in *every* name (of type, of function or method, of variable) related to debugging...

Comment: assert isn't always usable. Lots of times we just release our application as a debug build. It makes sense because we spend most of the time running debug builds during development. Unless we need the speed gains, why risk getting different behavior because we switched to a release build despite spending most of our time testing in debug builds.  And yes, I have experienced more than ample times where the debug and release builds ran differently from each other. Plus, it's always nice to be able to remotely attach a debugger to an application when it is misbehaving in the field.